# Calculate optimal stop loss from MAE or MFE

Tags: stop-loss

I have a list of trades. For each trade I have the following information

- Entry date and time
- Exit date and time
- P/L
- MAE (Maximum Adverse Excursion, sometimes called within trade drawdown)
- MFE (Maximum Favorable Excursion, sometimes called within trade run-up)

I use TradeStation, and currently, to calculate the stop loss, I manually observe the Maximum Adverse Excursion chart and attempt few values where I think it might be good a fit. A threshold which will remove quite a few big losses and relatively few big wins.

For example
[image]

Green dots: profitable trades

Red dots: losing trades (absolute value of P/L is plotted)

What I'm looking for is a way, to calculate the stop loss (or boundary if you will) automatically, from the trades list.
Personally I prefer Python. But any formula, paper, or programming language / pseudo code would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward minimisation problem, for which there are many routines available in Python, e.g. [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html).

You just need to minimise a trade metric of choice such as max drawdown, or alternatively to minimise the negative of a trade metric that you want to maximise, e.g. minimise the -TradeExpectancy

Comment: Thanks for the info, I may have thought about it too much graphically.